# Find Regexp and replace expression for CSV file starting with $

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I need an Regexp and Replace expression to capture contents from CSV file. My CSV file starts like this.

Example- expression should find key name "FC_host" in my CSV file and replace with different value.

```
$TH_appName=tuipatthcrfh3320
#$TH_host=10.145.129.75
$TH_host=10.145.129.75
$TH_casPort=8500;
$TH_eacPort=8888;
$FC_appName=tuipatfc3320;
#$FC_host=10.145.129.75
$FC_host=10.145.129.75
$FC_casPort=8500;
$FC_eacPort=8888;
```

Below is my code. This code works but has few issues.Kindly help me on this.Moreover I am using regexp and replace so that I need to update them in remote server.

```
    ---
  - hosts: local
    vars:
      properties:
      - { name: "TH_appName", value: "10.0.1" }
    tasks:
      - name: Find and Replace
        replace:
          dest: /etc/ansible/kalyan-tui/example.csv
          regexp: '(.*){{ item.name }}=(.*);'
          replace: '\1{{ item.name }}={{ item.value }};'
         # state: present
        with_items:
          - "{{ properties }}"
```

Comment: Your excerpt is not even close to being in CSV format...

Comment: \$ should escape the special character $

Comment: Seems as if your search/replace is some module of a framework and ``${{...}}`` look like template replacements. Did you try common regular expressions on this? Sth like ``'\$TH_appName=.+?\n'`` as regex and ``'$TH_appName=myNewValue\n'`` as replacement?

Comment: You don't need regex to replace a substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task should look like this:

```
- name: Find and Replace
  replace:
    dest: /etc/ansible/kalyan-tui/example.csv
    regexp: ^\$FC_host=.*
    replace: "$FC_host={{ new_value }}"
```

---

- `state` is not a parameter of `replace`
- variable name cannot contain spaces
- you don't need to quote the `regexp` value
- you don't need to escape dollar sign in the replacement value

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('items.csv', 'r')as file:
for row in file:
    print row.replace('TH_host', 'Something else')

>>$TH_appName=tuipatthcrfh3320
>>#$Something else=10.145.129.75
>>$Something else=10.145.129.75
>>...
```

You don't need regex unless you need to use the regular expressions such as a number of digits or a certain number of spaces. Regex is very expensive and therefore should be [avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782586/speed-of-many-regular-expressions-in-python) if possible.